# Does MySQL included with MAMP not include a config file?

Tags: mysql, mamp

I can't seem to find the my.cnf or other config file for the MySQL that comes with [MAMP](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html). Does it not include one?

Answer (score 210, accepted):

The MySQL server of MAMP (not PRO) will be started without any my.cnf file. But you can create your own my.cnf file.

1. Stop servers
2. Create a `my.cnf` file in `/Applications/MAMP/conf/`
3. Add your content in to `my.cnf`
4. Save `my.cnf`
5. Start servers

You do not have to put a complete configuration in the my.cnf file. You can just add parts of a configuration ... for example:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 64M
```

Comment: Note that MAMP Pro will create its own version. You can edit it more "nicely," though it's a bit of a pain for people used to the command line. Just go File->Edit Template->MySQL my.cnf, and change whatever settings you need. More info on both MAMP and MAMP pro [here](http://blog-en.mamp.info/2010/02/how-to-set-mysql-default-storage-engine.html).

Comment: Manually adding the my.cnf file to Application/MAMP/conf/ solved ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 1357: MySQL server has gone away. This post is old but still relevant for MAMP Version 3.0.2 (not pro)

Comment: +1 for the `max_allowed_packet`. How did you know **exactly** what I was looking for?

Comment: Thanks for including the [mysqld] line. I was missing that and banging my head against the wall why MAMP couldn't start up.

Comment: @Yasky, well, looks like at least 15 people that use MAMP have probably encountered '#2006 MySQL server has gone away', googled it, found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away) SO question, and then came here to find out where the my.cnf file is!

Comment: I use MAMP 5.3 and  have my.cnf in the following locations but they are all ignored obviously (yes i restarted the mysql service): ./MAMP/Library/my.cnf
./MAMP/my.cnf
./MAMP/apache/my.cnf

Comment: Thank you, I've spent all day trying to figure this out. I flushed the cache of my drupal 8 project and it gave this error 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away'. Above was the correct solution.

Answer (score 11):

Some standard my.cnf variants can be found at /Applications/MAMP/Library/support-files/

Invoking `mysqld --verbose --help | less` on the MAMP mysqld binary reports:

> Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
>   /etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /Applications/MAMP/conf/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Copy one of the variants in /Applications/MAMP/Library/support-files/ to one of the locations in mysqld's search order above, and you should be good to go after restarting the daemon.

Answer (score 10):

Since MAMP server generates `my.cnf` dynamically on MAMP server startup, it's best  to use the following steps to add or edit the MySQL configuration:

1. Stop MAMP server
2. Goto Files > Edit Template > MySQL
3. Make the necessary changes and save
4. Restart MAMP

I tried this on MAMP PRO 3.5.

Comment: Thank you! I knew there was a way to do this through MAMP

Comment: add "  innodb_force_recovery = 1"

Answer (score 10):

For MAMP 3.5 on Mac El Capitan, only this worked for me:

1. Stop servers
2. Create a `my.cnf` file in `/Applications/MAMP/Library/`
3. Add your content into `my.cnf` like

   `[mysqld]
    max_allowed_packet = 64M`
4. Save `my.cnf`
5. Start servers

Not required to change ownership of file, it should work. Verify by running `SHOW VARIABLES` in phpmyadmin and look for your changed setting.

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't come with the my.cnf file

Answer (score 1):

I found that MAMP PRO will create a my.cnf by default on startup under the MAMP/tmp directory if a ~/my.cnf is not provided ... grepping ps aux you may find the default location under /Applications/MAMP/tmp/my.cnf ...

```
 ps aux | grep mysql
```

Which provided the following...

```
root       284   0.0  0.1  2435544    532   ??  Ss    12:00AM   0:00.06 /bin/sh     /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld_safe 
--defaults-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/my.cnf 
--port=8889 --socket=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock 
--user=mysql --pid-file=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid 
--log-error=/Applications/MAMP/logs/mysql_error_log.err 
--tmpdir=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/tmpdir 
--datadir=/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/db/mysql
```