# Location of my.cnf file on macOS

Tags: mysql, database, macos

I'm trying to follow along [this tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html) to enable remote access to MySQL. The problem is, where should `my.cnf` file be located? I'm using Mac OS X Lion.

Comment: I think this belongs to serverfault.com. But still, welcome to SO!

Answer (score 274, accepted):

[This thread on the MySQL forum](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,366143,376017#msg-376017) says:

> *By default, the OS X installation does not use a my.cnf, and MySQL just uses the default values. To set up your own my.cnf, you could just create a file straight in /etc.*

OS X provides example configuration files at `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`.

And if you can't find them there, MySQLWorkbench can create them for you by:

1. Opening a connection.
2. In the left column select "Administration" tab and then the "Options File" under "INSTANCE" in the menu.
3. MySQL Workbench will search for `my.cnf` and if it can't find it, it'll create it for you.

Comment: Thanks!! So just in /usr/etc? Or should I make some kind of mysql directory there? :) *edit* Found the answer to that on the link, thanks!

Comment: At least the current MySQL package for Mac OS X (mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64 at the time of this writing) _does_ in fact create and use a my.cnf. It is located at /usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/my.cnf

Comment: you may want to ensure that mysql is actually loading in whichever `my.cnf` file you're editing via `mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf`

Comment: create /Applications/MAMP/Library/my.cnf for OSX El Capitan

Comment: On Mac OS Sierra, it wasn't set up already. I had to copy /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf to my.cnf in the same dir. Note that the mysql is symlinked to the package, in my case mysql-5.7.17-macos10.12-x86_64.

Comment: Just did a clean install of MySQL 5.7.19 on Mac OS 10.12 using the .dmg from dev.mysql.com. There's no my.cnf in any of the places that mysql --help says it looks in. And there's no my-default.cnf in /usr/local/mysql/support-files/ or anywhere else I've found. Turns out that ["as of MySQL 5.7.18, my-default.cnf is no longer included in or installed by distribution packages"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-configuration-defaults.html).

Comment: In the same situation as Chris, Mac 10.12.6, native MySQL 5.7.19, I was able to get MySQL Workbench to generate a default configuration file at `/etc/my.cnf` with a default mysqld section, but I don't think it is taking effect.  The file was still empty, so I used that program to show the diff, copied it into a text editor to save with admin permissions, restarted, but still nothing.  I wanted to enable named pipes, the socket, and disable the network communication, but doesn't seem to change anything, or it enabled the socket, but did not disable the normal networking connection path.

Comment: Where is "INSTANCE" in the menu? Which menu? My screenshot : https://imgur.com/a/KyiIwGM

Comment: think different

Comment: This answer is old and depends on which installer you used to install mysql.  Homebrew puts it one place, the dmg installer puts it another

Comment: As on date, in step 3, the Workbench just says "Location of conf file not specified" and it doesn't generate a new one automatically.

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75540862/6134928

Answer (score 90):

In case of Mac OS X Maverick when MySQL is installed via Homebrew it's located at `/usr/local/opt/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment: which is /usr/local/Cellar/yourMySqlVersion/my.cnf

Comment: /usr/local/opt/mariadb/VERSIONNUMBER/ in my case MariaDB is installed

Comment: Mine is in /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

Comment: Mine was `/usr/local/mysql/etc`. I'm on High Sierra but it was installed a few versions back.

Comment: I checked there, and haven't found it. I finally found that it is in a hidden folder there: .bottle/etc/my.cnf

I copied the my.cnf out and modified it. After restart mysql, it worked.

Answer (score 87):

In general, on Unix and Unix-like systems, MySQL/MariaDB programs read config/startup files in the following locations (in the specified order):

- `/etc/my.cnf` -   Global
- `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` - Global
- `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf` - Global

  > `SYSCONFDIR` represents the directory specified with the `SYSCONFDIR` option to `CMake` when MySQL was built. By default, this is the etc directory located under the compiled-in installation directory.
- `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf` -    Server-specific (server only)

  > `MYSQL_HOME` is an environment variable containing the path to the directory in which the server-specific `my.cnf` file resides. If `MYSQL_HOME` is not set and you start the server using the `mysqld_safe` program, `mysqld_safe` sets it to `BASEDIR`, the MySQL base installation directory.
- file specified with `--defaults-extra-file=path` if any
- `~/.my.cnf` - User-specific
- `~/.mylogin.cnf` - User-specific (clients only)

<sup>Source: [Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html).</sup>

> Note: On Unix platforms, MySQL ignores configuration files that are world-writable. This is intentional as a security measure.

---

Additionally on Mac there is a simple way to check it.

1. Run: `sudo fs_usage | grep my.cnf`

   <sup>This will report any filesystem activity in real-time related to that file.</sup>
2. In another Terminal, restart your MySQL/MariaDB, e.g.

   ```
   brew services restart mysql
   ```

   or:

   ```
   brew services restart mariadb
   ```
3. On terminal with `fs_usage`, the proper location should be shown, e.g.

   ```
   15:52:22  access            /usr/local/Cellar/mariadb/10.1.14/my.cnf                                         0.000002   sh
   ```

   So if the file doesn't exist, create one.

Comment: Thanks! the  `sudo fs_usage | grep my.cnf` method is quite efficient. I find this file on folder: **/usr/local/etc/my.cnf**

Comment: Great method, however I get several results there:
`private/etc/my.cnf`, `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf`, `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/<myVersion>/my.cnf`, `~.my.cnf`with `my_print_def` in the right-most column. Then after a while it's only `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` with my terminal in the right-most column.
But all of these `my.cnf` files don't exist!

Comment: @Andru If none of them exists, create a new one.

Comment: @kenorb Ok. At any of the listed locations?
And what does actually happen there if the `my.cnf` files don't exist? Is it showing that it searches for `my.cnf` files there? What would be the order in which they are read? Or is just used? If so, which one?

Comment: @Andru In any location that is read. If config doesn't exist, MySQL uses the default settings.

Comment: Your last set of instructions re sudo fs_usage | grep my.cnf was the only thing that helped me on this page, as for some unknown reason mysqld was not loading from the default locations listed via mysql -?

Comment: when I execute `fs_usage` in my Mac terminal, it spilled out 'fs_usage' must be run as root... Do you have any idea what is going on and what to do with it?
I did some search and executed this:

% sudo fs_usage
Password:
ktrace_start: Resource busy

Comment: "On Unix platforms, MySQL ignores configuration files that are world-writable" helped solve my issue, thanks!  I changed the permissions and it started reading the config file.  I would suggest there's a flaw in the mysqld logic that it keeps running by default.  If I were mysqld and I saw a config file in the "top-most" location (/etc/my.cnf), and I'm unwilling to read it due to permissions, and I *haven't* been provided an option that explicitly tells me "sure, just skip right on past config files until you can read one", I would error out and stop running.  But I guess I'm not mysqld...yet.

Answer (score 37):

If you are using macOS Sierra and the file doesn't exists,
run

`mysql --help or mysql --help | grep my.cnf`

to see the possible locations and loading/reading sequence of my.cnf for mysql then create my.cnf file in one of the suggested directories then add the following line

`[mysqld] sql_mode = STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`

You can `sudo touch /{preferred-path}/my.cnf` then edit the file to add sql mode by

`sudo nano /{preferred-path}/my.cnf`

Then restart MySQL.

Answer (score 36):

I don't know which version of MySQL you're using, but here are possible locations of the my.cnf file for version 5.5 (taken from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)) on Mac OS X:

1. `/etc/my.cnf`
2. `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
3. `SYSCONFDIR/my.cnf`
4. `$MYSQL_HOME/my.cnf`
5. `defaults-extra-file` (the file specified with `--defaults-extra-file=path`, if any)
6. `~/.my.cnf`

Answer (score 21):

For MySQL 5.7 on Mac OS X El Capitan: `/usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf`

Copy default conf from `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf`

Comment: Just to be clear, you have to create "etc/" folder yourself and you need root privileges for that "sudo su -"

Comment: Not found in that location for me . I am using MAMP

Comment: @mirzavu, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678645/does-mysql-included-with-mamp-not-include-a-config-file

Answer (score 19):

I'm running MacOS Catalina(10.15.3) and find `my.cnf` in `/usr/local/etc`.

Answer (score 16):

macOS sierra 10.12.6
MySQL version : 5.7.18_1
I run *locate my.cnf* and the path is

> /usr/local/etc/my.cnf

Comment: consider adding explanation to your asnwer

Comment: @charles.cc.hsu: try using command ```locate my.cnf``` on your terminal. what the result ?

Answer (score 15):

The [current MySQL package for Mac OS X Mavericks](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/) (mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64 at the time of this writing) automatically creates a my.cnf during installation.

It is located at `/usr/local/mysql-5.6.17-osx10.7-x86_64/my.cnf`
Adapt your path according to your version.

Answer (score 13):

So none of these things worked for me.  I am using the current dmg install of mysql community server.  ps shows that all of the most critical parameters normally in my.cnf are passed on the command line, and I couldn't figure out where that was coming from.  After doing a full text search of my box I found it in:

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld.plist`

So you can either change them there, or take them out so it will actually respect the ones you have in your my.cnf wherever you decided to put it.

Enjoy!

Example of the file info found in that file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>             <string>com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld</string>
    <key>ProcessType</key>       <string>Interactive</string>
    <key>Disabled</key>          <false/>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>         <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>         <true/>
    <key>SessionCreate</key>     <true/>
    <key>LaunchOnlyOnce</key>    <false/>
    <key>UserName</key>          <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>GroupName</key>         <string>_mysql</string>
    <key>ExitTimeOut</key>       <integer>600</integer>
    <key>Program</key>           <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld</string>
            <string>--user=_mysql</string>
            <string>--basedir=/usr/local/mysql</string>
            <string>--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data</string>
            <string>--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin</string>
            <string>--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err</string>
            <string>--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid</string>
             <string>--keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring</string>
             <string>--early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so</string>

        </array>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>  <string>/usr/local/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: great! you saved my day.

Comment: I had the same case, but I also had to add my.cnf file to `/etc/my.cnf`

Answer (score 13):

You can create your file under any directory you want. After creation, you can "tell" the path to mysql config:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can open a terminal and type `locate my.cnf`

Comment: Sorry to not be specific enough, I apparently need to copy 'my-large.cnf' to some folder and rename it 'my.cnf'. But I don't know to where..

Comment: also, you do need to have a populated locate db. on mac osx: sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.locate.plist

Answer (score 11):

In mysql 5.6.22, which I installed it from Homebrew, the path of my.cnf is

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql/my.cnf
```

Answer (score 11):

Open Terminal and use below command:

```
sudo find / -name my.cnf
```

Answer (score 9):

In case of installing MySQL with Homebrew in Mac M1 with MacOS Monterey 12.0.1 the location is /opt/homebrew/etc/my.cnf

Answer (score 7):

You can check the file

`/usr/local/bin/mysql.server` and see from where `my.conf` is being read from.

Usually it is from `/etc/my.cnf` or `~/my.cnf` or `~/.my.cnf`

Comment: Correction: `~/.my.cnf`. Add a dot before the file name.

Answer (score 7):

## READ THE DOCS!

The MySQL Documents for which version you are using will help.
It is usually described as a `Options File` or `MySQL Config File`.
The docs have the location of these files in the documentation, As well as other `VITAL` information like the location & small examples of what the config file must look like.

[MySQL Version 8](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)

[MySQL Version 5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html)

[MySQL Version 5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html)

[MySQL Version 5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/option-files.html)

[MySQL Version 5.6 Japanese](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/option-files.html)

### Important Notes:

> On Unix platforms, MySQL ignores configuration files that are world-writable.
>
> This is intentional as a security measure.

In other words, if you have the wrong permissions set on your config file the will NOT load.

Example of initial setup permission of one of the config files:

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ ls -lah /etc/my.cnf
-rw-r--r--  1 myusername  wheel     0B Feb 25 20:40 /etc/my.cnf
```

### Note:

> It is possible to use `!include` directives in option files to include other option files and `!includedir` to search specific directories for option files.....
>
> ...**MySQL makes no guarantee about the order in which option files in the directory will be read**...
>
> Any files to be found and included using the !includedir directive on Unix operating systems must have file names ending in `.cnf`. On Windows, this directive checks for files with the `.ini` or `.cnf` extension.

Examples of how to find your location of your config or log files ect.:

### SQL

This will not show you the config file but will help you locate your installation files/folders.

MySQL Version 5.7 & 8+

```
SELECT * FROM PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE LIKE '%\/%';
```

MySQL Version <= 5.6

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.GLOBAL_VARIABLES WHERE VARIABLE_VALUE LIKE '%\/%';
```

### SHELL/Terminal

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

Above Command Credit To: [Erwin Mayer](https://serverfault.com/a/775553/186696) from ServerFault

```
RIZZOMBP$ mysqld --verbose --help | grep '/my.cnf' -B 1

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

OR

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ ps aux | grep -i mysqld | grep -v $USER

_mysql 106 0.4 2.5 4232336 422112 ?? Ss 7:01PM 0:57.12
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld
--user=_mysql
--basedir=/usr/local/mysql
--datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
--plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin
--log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err
--pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid
--keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring
--early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so
```

### Sample File

Should you need a detailed Reference Sample my.cnf:

1. https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=my.cnf+mysql&ref=searchresults
2. https://www.linode.com/community/questions/5749/mysql-sample-config-files
3. https://www.fromdual.com/mysql-configuration-file-sample

> No affiliation/association to the URL's

### My System:

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.3
BuildVersion:   18D109
```

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 8.0.15 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

```sh
RIZZOMBP$ mysqld -V
/usr/local/mysql-8.0.15-macos10.14-x86_64/bin/mysqld 
Ver 8.0.15 for macos10.14 on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)
```

Comment: mysql --help | grep "Default options" -A 1 . this helped.

Answer (score 6):

**macOS 13 and MySQL 8 current if installed directly from the MySQL Installer from Oracle:**

By default, no `my.cnf` will be created. To get a default one created easily without needing to use any Terminal commands, here is how:

1. Open MySQL Workbench on your Mac. Connect into your localhost instance of MySQL.
2. Click the little wrench icon next to **INSTANCE** on the left pane above Startup / Shutdown.
3. Select macOS as System Type, macOS as Installation Type, and the rest will default into place. Copy the location it gives you for the `my.cnf` file.
4. Click Close
5. Now click Options File on the left. It will notice that you don't have a file and will show you default values.
6. Click the Apply... in the bottom right corner.
7. It will then ask you for a password of your current logged in user of your Mac to create and save the `my.cnf` file.
8. Now in the Finder use the keyboard combo of Command-Shift-G and copy in your location we copied earlier (i.e. `/etc/my.cnf`)

Answer (score 5):

For MAMP 3.5 Mac El Capitan, create a separate empty config file and write your additional settings for mysql

```
sudo vim /Applications/MAMP/Library/my.cnf
```

And Add like this

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet = 256M
```

Answer (score 3):

macOS High Sierra
version 10.13.6

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.22, for osx10.13 (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:

```
/etc/my.cnf 
/etc/mysql/my.cnf 
/usr/local/etc/my.cnf 
~/.my.cnf
```

Answer (score 3):

/private/etc/my.cnf for Catalina

Answer (score 2):

I checked in macOS Sierra, the homebrew installed `MySql 5.7.12`

The support files are located at

```
/usr/local/opt/mysql/support-files
```

Just copy `my-default.cnf` as `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and the configuration will be picked up on restart.

Comment: I just installed 5.7.18 on 12.12.4 via homebrew and they are not there.

Answer (score 2):

it should be usually under `/usr/local/etc` on mac if you do not find it you can create one

Answer (score 2):

a quick way to figure out on MAC OS was the following:

```bash
sudo find /usr/ -type f -iname "*my.cnf*"
```

or

```bash
brew list mysql@5.7 |grep -i my.cnf
```

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I am using mysql version 5.7.17 in macOS High Sierra version 10.13.3 and I have found the mysql config file here.

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on finding the default configuration file. Note, this is just a template file so you'll want to copy this to a location found in `mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf` where it will get picked up, as per: `DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE. It's a template which will be copied to the default location during install, and will be replaced if you upgrade to a newer version of MySQL.`

Answer (score 1):

For mysql 8.0.19, I finally found the my.cnf here:
/usr/local/opt/mysql/.bottle/etc
I copied it to 
/usr/local/opt/mysql/
and modified it. Then I restart the mysql service, it works.

Comment: Works for me on BigSur with 8.0 installed via homebrew, thanks

Answer (score 0):

For Mac , what worked for me is creating a .my.cnf file in my ~ path. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Copy /usr/local/opt/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf as /etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf and then restart mysql.

Answer (score 0):

For me in sierra version

copy the default configuration at:

> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.27/support-files/my-default.cnf

to

> /usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.6.27/my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the file did not exist. In MySQL Workbench I went to OPTIONS FILE and found some default values. I clicked apply. It asked for permission. It then created the my.cnf file under /etc. However, it is very important to keep in mind that the first time you click "apply", you do not make any changes to the default configuration. Once the file has been created, you can make changes which will be applied when you click "apply". Otherwise you will not be shown the apply button when you make changes.

Comment: I have an options file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` but MySQL Workbench is not aware of it. Instead, it complains that the configuration file with an empty path cannot be found and then offers to create a new file.

Answer (score 0):

After the 5.7.18 version of MySQL, it does not provide the default configuration file in support-files directory.
So you can create my.cnf file **manually** in the location where MySQL will read, like /etc/mysql/my.cnf, and add the configuration you want to add in the file.

Answer (score 0):

rDefault options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf

Answer (score 0):

I'm running MacOS Mojave (10.14.6) and to get MySQL to recognize my config file, I had to place it in  /usr/local/mysql-5.7.26-macos10.14-x86_64/etc/my.cnf. Also I have a symbolic link pointing to it from  /usr/local/@mysql/etc/my.cnf .

I was trying to turn off sql_mode=only_full_group_by and setting that option in the config file was the only way I could get the setting to persist across sessions. The contents of the config file are:

```
[mysqld]
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
```

I'm using the native install of MySQL, not the Homebrew set up.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to all these great answers. If you are working in an environment where you don't get sudo access. Your Homebrew could have been installed in your home directory `~` if that's the case and your mysql has been installed by `brew install mysql` your my.cnf could be located in `~/homebrew/etc/my.cnf` alternatively you could just search for it in your home `find ./ -name 'my.cnf'`