# Where does MySQL on OSX write outfiles by default?

Tags: mysql, macos, into-outfile

I'm trying to write some data from a MySQL select statement to a file on a Mac running Snow Leopard.

```
select date_base, fractile_v2, gics, count(gvkey_iid)
from master
where fractile_v2 <= 15 and
      fractile_v2  != 0
group by date_base, gics, fractile_v2
order by date_base, fractile_v2
limit 100000
INTO OUTFILE '/User/my-name/Desktop/gics_v2.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';
```

Unfortunately this generates the following error:

> Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file '/Users/andrew/Desktop/gics_v2.csv' (Errcode: 13)

which I'm assuming is a permissions issue.

When I replace the full file path `'/User/my-name/Desktop/gics_v2.csv'` with simply `gics_v2.csv` the statements seems to run. However I have no idea where the file is saved and I can't find it.

Does anyone know? And can anyone also suggest how I can solve the initial write error? I'm running MySQL as the root user.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cannot-create.html) helps.  For what's it's worth, `find / -name "gics_v2.csv"` as root should locate the file on your computer

Comment: @BenM thanks Ben, I had to use 'sudo' to find it but it's under /usr/local/mysql-5.5.17-osx10.6-x86_64/data/. You help it much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a permissions issue because you're trying to get the mysql user to write to your private home directory.  Try writing to a folder you create in /usr/local/ instead and just to be safe, you can make permissions global read/write since it's your Mac.

Open Terminal on your Mac:

> cd /usr/local
>
> mkdir DbOutput
>
> sudo chmod -R 777 DbOutput

Then back to your code but change path:

> select date_base, fractile_v2, gics, count(gvkey_iid)
>
> from master
>
> where fractile_v2 <= 15 and
>
> fractile_v2  != 0
>
> group by date_base, gics, fractile_v2
>
> order by date_base, fractile_v2
>
> limit 100000
>
> INTO OUTFILE '/usr/local/DbOutput/gics_v2.csv'
>
> FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',';

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. I'm going to have to play around with the permissions a bit I think. It's been a while since I'd done this stuff. I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem.  I've been using this site so much lately I felt the need to give back.  This is my first answer and vote so thanks to you as well.  ;-)

Comment: I don't agree with this -- it doesn't really answer the question, and advising someone to make directories 777 is kind of a hack.  Better to use more appropriate permissions.

Comment: Also, check `secure_file_priv`  http://stackoverflow.com/a/10757312/5973334

Answer (score 2):

By default SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE puts the files in the directory where the data files live. So something like `/path/to/datadir/databasename/gics_v2.csv`

It writes files as the server, not the client.  So it's not using your user's permissions, but rather the user that is running the mysqld process (which is usually _mysql on osx.)

You simply have to give it a path where that user is allowed to write.

Comment: thanks for your help. I found where it was writing it to and created a new specific directory and gave the server user permission to write into. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is out of date, but just FYI, on my Mac OS X 10.10, the `OUTPUT` directory is something like this: `/usr/local/mysql-5.7.10-osx10.9-x86_64/data/databasename/***.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

I am running Mac OS X Server 10.7.4 and for me, the OUTFILE directory is `/var/mysql/databasename/`