# How to handle Broken piper error when writing to a table using mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-python

The data I'm trying to insert into my table has about 95k rows. So in essence I'm trying to insert 95k values using the executemany(sql, data) function.

My initial suspicion is that the number of sets of values being inserted is too much for the executemany() function to handle. Any ideas if that is indeed the cause or if there is anything else that could be causing the following error message?

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/ssrikanthan/anaconda/envs/ilc-load/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py",
>   line 130, in send_plain
>       self.sock.sendall(packet) BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try increasing the `max_allowed_packet` variable:

```
set global max_allowed_packet=262144000;
```

We can update the same from MySQL Config also as:

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=250M
```

Once updating the config you need to restart MySQL services to take effect and this is the best way to update variables. setting variables from queries is not good because values updated to defaults when MySQL services restarts.

Default value of this variable is `1MB` which is not enough in some case like yours which includes large data insertion. so ,while performing large data operations like insertion,updation and dumping data from MySQL then this variable should be updated. Max limit to this variable `1GB` but setting it to to `250 MB` is enough in all the cases generally.

Comment: getting back `mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
`

Comment: Yes you need to have SUPER privilege to set this variable.

Comment: @user4659009: You can also update it from MySQL config file,if you have access otherwise your DB user should have  SUPER privilege to update this. Check the updated answer.

Comment: I'm using mysql workbench, I can't find where I'm meant to update the max_allowed_packet, any ideas where I might be able to find it?

Comment: You are running MySQL on windows OS?

Comment: On Mac OS unfortunately

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location . It contains information related to MySQL config location in MAC OS. Try to find the config and update the variable as per the answer.