# Cannot find any .cnf for Mysql installed on OSX El Capitan

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan, my.cnf

I'm doing load data infile with MySQL on OSX El Capitan, however, the following error happened:

> ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement

I try to fix it my modify my.cnf or use any .cng in /usr/local/mysql/support-files
to create a my.cnf file.
But there isn't any file with .cnf extension.
Here is file list in /usr/local/mysql/support-files:

```
magic           mysql.server
```

`mysql-log-rotate   mysqld_multi.server`
Could any body provide me the path to .cnf in OSX?

Comment: Or any other way that could help me to fix this problem

Comment: There are several answers on Stackoverflow regarding the location of the my.cnf file. For example, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location-on-os-x

Answer (score 0):

Instead of solving the problem, I downgraded the mysql to 5.6, and then added and modified the parameter in my.cnf following lots of answer to the similar question about mysql 5.6.