# ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 15.29.92.100 (61)

Tags: mysql, macos

I have installed mysql on mac os sierra using the instructions given here

https://gist.github.com/nrollr/a8d156206fa1e53c6cd6

after the installation.

1 I disabled the mac firewall. 
2 I did the following:

```
mysqladmin -v -uroot -pXXXX
mysql -uroot -p
create user 'foo'@'%' identify by 'YYYYY';
flush privileges;
```

3 restarted mysql service

I can very easily connect to mysql using user foo locally. but when i try to connect remotely. I get the error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '15.20.95.200' (61)
```

Searched the internet and there are a million answers to this problem which have been solved by messing around with `my.cnf`. But on mac OS Sierra. there is no my.cnf file.

I do have a file

```
/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/support-files/mysql.server
```

I copied this file to `/etc/my.cnf` and added line

```
[mysqld] 
bind-address=0.0.0.0
```

restarted mysql `brew services restart mysql`

but still i get the same problem.

Edit:: My IP address is not wrong. I can ping the machine remotely. I can use the remote desktop and connect to the machine running mysql using the Same IP address. in fact right now I am connected to the machine using remote desktop and working on mysql locally. using the same login id foo.

its just the mysql command line fails.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/mysql-my-cnf-location-on-os-x

Comment: I have already mentioned that in my thread. the file is present at `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/support-files/mysql.server
` but it doesn't have the settings people play around with.

Comment: So copy it as `/etc/my.cnf` and insert a string `bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many days of enormous suffering. I finally solved the problem.

On "MAC OSX" you have to look for a file called `homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

I found this file in `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.7.18_1/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist`

This file will look like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

You have to change this file to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>KeepAlive</key>
  <true/>
  <key>Label</key>
  <string>homebrew.mxcl.mysql</string>
  <key>ProgramArguments</key>
  <array>
    <string>/usr/local/opt/mysql/bin/mysqld_safe</string>
    <string>--datadir=/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
    <string>--bind-address=0.0.0.0</string>
  </array>
  <key>RunAtLoad</key>
  <true/>
  <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
  <string>/usr/local/var/mysql</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Now restart mysql by `brew services restart mysql` Remote connections work perfectly now.

All the tomfoolery with my.cnf does not work on MAC OSX when you use HOMEBREW to install mysql.