# I dont have the my.cnf file, how do i increase the thread_stack size mysql?

Tags: mysql, terminal

I have just had a look at this question [Location of my.cnf file on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos/10757312]) and it would have been usefull for me however i have the same problem as one of the commenters (Chris Bartley) who also did an install of MySQL 5.7.19 on Mac OS 10.12 using the .dmg. i think this is the reason for the file not being on my laptop.

But i have a problem with a recursive procedure that sais

> Thread stack overrun:  135608 bytes used of a 262144 byte stack, and
>   128000 bytes needed.  Use 'mysqld --thread_stack=#' to specify a
>   bigger stack.

and unfortunately i havent found anywhere on the internet that was able to help.

**If i don't have the my.cnf file how do i configure mysql settings like those who do?**

Comment: I highly advice you fix the query, clearly it has a major problem if it can recurses so deep it hits the stack limit.

Comment: You can create a `my.cnf` file if you want to override the defaults.

Comment: Thanks for your advise geoffrey it has helped me progress however, can i still have an answer to this question please. how do i create a my.cnf file on mac Barmar or anyone that can answer?