# PHP with MySQL 8.0+ error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm running MySQL version 8 on PHP 7.0.

I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to my database from PHP:

> Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

PHP might show this error

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in D:\xampp\htdocs\reg\server.php on line 10

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I did some Google work. Maybe this will work? https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392 (not the same problem, but it's the same error message)

Comment: For folks who stumble across this and are having no success: I also got this error message when I had the wrong IP for the database in my .env file.

Answer (score 516):

@mohammed, this is usually attributed to the authentication plugin that your mysql database is using.

By default and for some reason, mysql 8 default plugin is auth_socket. Applications will most times expect to log in to your database using a **password**.

If you have not yet already changed your mysql default authentication plugin, you can do so by:
 1. Log in as root to mysql
 2. Run this sql command:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

Replace 'password' with your root password. In case your application does not log in to your database with the root user, replace the 'root' user in the above command with the user that your application uses.

Digital ocean expounds some more on this here [Installing Mysql](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-ubuntu-18-04#step-2-%E2%80%94-installing-mysql)

Comment: The main reason for this problem is that Mysql's default authentication plug-in support has changed in the 8.0 release of MariaDB. For example, the list of Mysql authentication plug-ins supported by 'PHP7.3' can be seen through the 'phpinfo()' function:` mysqlnd debug_trace, auth_plugin_mysql_native_password auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password, auth_plugin_sha256_password `. So change the authentication plugin mechanism in the Mysql server restricted account to 'sha256_password' or 'mysql_native_password': 
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH sha256_password BY 'password';

Comment: I get `ERROR 1396 (HY000): Operation ALTER USER failed for 'root'@'localhost'` for this. My password is `''` (empty)

Comment: It doesn't work for 8.0.20. The command ALTER USER succeeded but the warning still appears.

Comment: Thanks for this. I added [mysqld]
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password to mysql (8) config file but this did the trick.

Comment: This worked for me BUT with one added caveat on macOS Big Sur, MySQL 8.0.15: ALTER USER CURRENT_USER() IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';

Comment: BY GIVES ME AN ERROR

Comment: Got past the first error message, now getting the following:   
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: And then `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password' ... gave me a conflict error.
ALTER USER 'uname'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA mysql_native_password USING 'upass'.... worked for me.

Comment: @xjcl the reason the command failed is because you dont have user root@'%' - it is not the same as root@'localhost' alter only those who exists;

Answer (score 168):

You have to change MySQL settings.
Edit my.cnf file and put this setting in mysqld section:

```
[mysqld]
default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password
```

Then run following command:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Above command will bring into effect the changes of default authentication mechanism.

Comment: and then recreate the users. `ALTER USER $user IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'passwd'` (ref [ALTER USER manual page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-user.html)

Comment: $user is not a valid variable. not usefull

Comment: Found my.cnf on Ububtu at /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Comment: I don't see that line in mysql 8.0 on Ubuntu 19

Comment: @cyber8200 you can always add this line.

Comment: I don't see my.cnf in macbook

Comment: @AkshayHazari Please follow this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos

Comment: Where is my.cnf file on Windows 7?

Comment: @Clarity it depends on software you're using. You should find root directory of your MySQL or MariaDB first. Usually it's installed under Program Files, but it may vary if you're using packages like XAMP or WAMP.

Comment: Finally on Linux: `sudo service mysql restart`

Comment: Thank's that worked for me. I was using php 5.6

Comment: for what its worth, if your  user, pass, etc in the php mysqli_connect function are inccorect, it will also give the:
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [auth_gssapi_client].which i think has nothing to do with authentication method, but just the authentication in itself.  mariadb 10+

Answer (score 122):

I've tried a lot of other solutions, but only this works for me.

Thanks for the [workaround](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392#issuecomment-409612243).

**Check your .env**

```
MYSQL_VERSION=latest
```

**Then type this command**

```
$ docker-compose exec mysql bash
$ mysql -u root -p
```

**(login as root)**

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
ALTER USER 'default'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'secret';
```

Then go to phpmyadmin and login as :

- **host** -> mysql
- **user** -> root
- **password** -> root

Comment: this solution worked for me as a charm. U saved my day also! what I did additionally was to fork mysql docker and encase the solution in the build of mysql container: https://github.com/cybalex/mysql/commit/e5cb4cf80ca69066a185bfa7dfeeb44de93d4c31

Comment: Thank you. it helps a lot. I just need that last alter query to run this on docker mysql

Comment: `[HY000][1396] Operation ALTER USER failed for 'default'@'%'` happens on the last alter... any ideas?

Comment: @TaioliFrancesco thanks for your answer it works, but do we have to run theses queries each time w start mysql container ? is there a way to do it via docker compose ?

Comment: @SlimenTN no, only once and then the container rember the mysql setting

Comment: @TaioliFrancesco ok but you know when automating things via CI/CD tool we might need to drop containers and start new ones, are the settings will remain the same ?

Comment: i'm new in the ci/cd so i'm not the right person to ask, but i think  that if the container are the same the config will remain, otherwise if the container will be drop and rebuild at each new pipeline instance, the config won't remain the same

Comment: Can i put the empty password for root and how i can make it ?

Comment: @F.Dakia i haven't try it. One solution could run the first two commands and change the third one like this ALTER USER 'default'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '';

Comment: If you can rebuild container with your MySQL database I would rather recommend to check this solution - https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392#issuecomment-563011691. As an example, you can check how laradock made a setup for MySQL - https://github.com/laradock/laradock/tree/master/mysql.

Comment: Thanks, ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root'; work for me in connection remote

Answer (score 15):

None of the answers here worked for me. What I had to do is:

1. Re-run the installer.
2. Select the quick action 're-configure' next to product 'MySQL Server'
3. Go through the options till you reach Authentication Method and select 'Use Legacy Authentication Method'

After that it works fine.

Comment: If you used the installer and you're using the classic username/password method for connecting to your database, this method is the way to go.

Comment: I'm not finding Authentication Method in the installer :(

Comment: @CharlesWood You need to use the MYSQL Installer   https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

Answer (score 11):

Faced the same problem, I was not able to run wordpress docker container with mysql version 8 as its default authentication mechanism is caching_sha2_password instead of mysql_native_password.

In order to fix this problem we must reset default authentication mechanism to mysql_native_password.

Find my.cnf file in your mysql installation, usually on a linux machine it is at the following location - /etc/mysql

Edit my.cnf file and add following line just under heading [mysqld]

default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password

Save the file then log into mysql command line using root user

run command FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: This solution solves my problem, but I don't have to flush the privileges.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Laravel Lumen to build a small application.
For me it was because I didn't had the DB_USERNAME defined in my .env file.

```
DB_USERNAME=root
```

Setting this solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my.cnf file check below 2 steps.

- check this value -

  old_passwords=0;

  it should be 0.
- check this also-

  [mysqld] default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password Another
  value to check is to make sure

  [mysqld] section should be like this.

Comment: Where would you find the "my.cnf" file?

Comment: laradock/mysql/my.cnf

Answer (score -1):

```
preferences -> mysql -> initialize database -> use legacy password encryption(instead of strong) -> entered same password
```

as my **config.inc.php** file, restarted the apache server and it worked. I was still suspicious about it so I stopped the apache and mysql server and started them again and now it's working.