# MySQL 8.0 Requested authentication method unknown to the client (caching_sha2_password)

Tags: mysql, windows, symfony, doctrine-orm, mysql-8.0

**Environment**

- Microsoft Windows 10.0.16299.15
- PHP 7.2.11
- MySQL Community Server 8.0.13
- Symfony 4

I try to connect to MySQL database. When I

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create
```

, I have this:

> An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000][2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
>
> PDO::_construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP with MySQL 8.0+ error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to)

Answer (score 1):

You may check [Upgrading to MySQL 8.0 : Default Authentication Plugin Considerations](https://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-to-mysql-8-0-default-authentication-plugin-considerations/) to get information about important notes on upgrading to 8.0 where you will find:

> At the time of writing this post, following connectors do not have support for caching_sha2_password.
>
> - [PHP mysqli connector](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)
> - GO mysql connector
> - PERL DBD-mysql connector

If you want to know more, you may check [caching_sha2_password as the Preferred Authentication Plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrading-from-previous-series.html#upgrade-caching-sha2-password) on MySQL official documentation.

So, I think that's soon to upgrade to MySQL 8.0 and you may consider downgrade or wait some time for php mysql extension to be upgraded as well.

Comment: i have reconfigure in "authentification method"  and "use legacy authentification method (retain mysql (X. compatibility)"

Comment: This method seemed not to function for me (although it should for what I understand). So I had to reinstall the MySQL server via the Oracle installer and check the "use legacy authentication method" (like @Phil31971 I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using MySQL 8, the default method of authentication has changed, maybe you will need to change something in your server configuration.

Look this link: https://github.com/laradock/laradock/issues/1392#issuecomment-368308494

Another thing you can do is downgrade your MySQL version.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but i'm use symfony 4 i'll try to downgrade mysql later !!