# mysqli::__construct(): authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]x

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, xampp

I've just installed xampp and I'm running a MySQL db locally on phpMyAdmin. I'm trying to output the contents of a database via a .php doc, but I'm getting two warnings when trying to do so:

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in C:\xampp\htdocs\footfallTracker\test.php on line 20

Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client in C:\xampp\htdocs\footfallTracker\test.php on line 20
Connection failed: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Here's the code I'm using:

```
     <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "*2470C0C06DEE42FD1618BB99005ADCA2EC9D1E19";
$dbname = "footfall_tracking";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT ID, Location, Date FROM footstep_count";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["ID"]. " - Location: " . $row["Location"]. " - Date: " . $row["Date"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

This code helped me

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';
```

You can check it here :D
[The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to-the-client-php)
thi