# Can't configure MySQL with phpMyAdmin locally on Windows

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to configure my own local server on Windows 7 with binary versions of PHP, Apache, MySQL and phpMyAdmin. I configured and run Apache with PHP successfully.

Now I want to configure MySQL and phpMyAdmin. First I created the `my.cnf` file with the code

```
[mysqld]
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password
```

and next I run the CMD command

```
D:/Server/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --initialize --console
```

and got the `D:Server/mysql/data` folder with files therein

My HTML-files will be in the `D:/Server/localhost` folder. So I inserted unpacked phpMyAdmin folder there and added the following lines to its `config.in.php`

```
...
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['nopassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ServerDefault'] = 1;
```

Then I started MySQL with the command

```
D:/Server/mysql/bin/mysqld.exe --console
```

and in the command promt I get

```
.../mysqld.exe ready for connections
... X Plugin ready for connections
```

But now if I try to log in to phpMyAdmin with root username and empty password I get the error

> mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method
>   unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
>
> mysqli_real_connect():
>   (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to
>   the client

There on SO I read https://stackoverflow.com/a/52364450/3208225 but I already have the line `default_authentication_plugin= mysql_native_password` in my.cnf

I also read we can log in as root and set a password but I really don't understand how can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the problem was I initialized the `data` directory with the command

```
>mysqld.exe --initialize --console
```

which generates a temporary password, but I expected to log in without any password. So if we want to use empty password, we have to initialize the data directory with the command

```
>mysqld.exe --initialize-insecure --console
```

and we can set a password later

**Reference:** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-directory-initialization.html

Answer (score 0):

try setting your `['auth_type']` to: `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';`.

When I installed phpmyadmin, I made the same mistake.
Hope it works, for me it worked.

Kind regards.

Comment: Now when I go to `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php` I get the error `MySQL said: Documentation. Cannot connect: invalid settings.`