# mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

When I open phpmyadmin it displays an error at the bottom of the page, it connects fine but there's an error. I was getting this error before but it wasn't allowing the admin page to open so I fixed it by changing the auth method:

```
ALTER USER root IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'PASSWORD';
```

The error now only after login:

```
mysqli_real_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

It was working fine until I cleared the browser cookies. I can still use phpmyadmin.

This is displayed on the main page too:

```
The phpMyAdmin configuration storage is not completely configured, some extended features have been deactivated. Find out why. 
Or alternately go to 'Operations' tab of any database to set it up there.
```

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to

Comment: I've tried the solutions from those answers, logged into mysql server and altered user password and auth type, and modified my.ini to use: default_authentication_plugin = mysql_native_password

Comment: might be worth noting i'm using phpmyadmin from xampp