# Symfony; SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory while using 127.0.0.1 as database_host

Tags: mysql, macos, symfony, docker

The full error is `Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /app/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php on line 113`, but that's too long for the title.

I'm trying to set up a Symfony project locally, but I'm struggling to get the database connection to work. My `parameters.yml` looks as follows

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: database_name
    database_user: username
    database_password: password
```

I've been googling this issue a lot and most people seem to solve the issue by changing `database_host` from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, but this doesn't work for me. The app itself runs via Docker, but I've set up the database connection once via Brew and once with a MySQL server for Mac. In both cases I can connect via the command line and with SequelPro/TablePlus, but whenever I try to access the website through the browser I get the "No such file or directory" error.

I've also tried multiple ways of setting up a Docker MySQL container, but can't get it to work. My `docker-compose.yml` looks like this;

```
nginx:
  build: nginx
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
  links:
    - php
  volumes:
    - ../:/app

php:
  build: php-fpm
  volumes:
    - ../:/app
  working_dir: /app
  extra_hosts:
    - "site.dev: 172.17.0.1"

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database_name'
      MYSQL_USER: 'username'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password_root'
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    expose:
      - '3306'
    volumes:
      - my-db:/var/lib/mysql
```

But whenever I run `docker-compose up -d` I get the error `Unsupported config option for services: 'db'`.

Another attempt was adding

```
mysql:
  image: mysql:latest
  volumes:
    - mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD='password'
    - MYSQL_DATABASE='database_name'
    - MYSQL_USER='username'
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD='password'
```

To the docker-compose file, and while it does build the mysql image, I can't seem to connect to it with SequelPro/TablePlus. I ran `docker-inspect` on the container to get the IP (172.17.0.3), but can't seem to get access to it. I can `exec` into it, login using `mysql -u root` and create the required user and database, but then I'm still struggling to actually connect to it.

Running `docker ps` does show the sql container running btw;

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
b6de6030791d        docker_nginx        "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   19 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp   docker_nginx_1
f26b832bb005        docker_php          "docker-php-entrypoi…"   19 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       9000/tcp               docker_php_1
6c2a9e657435        mysql:latest        "docker-entrypoint.s…"   19 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp    docker_mysql_1
```

I also thought it might be an issue with changes to the `parameters.yml` file not properly syncing with the container as I'm using Mac (at my old workplace we had to use docker-sync to make sync changes between our dev environment and the actual container), but when inspecting the container itself using `exec` I can see the changes in the `parameters.yml` file.

Could the issue be it trying to connect to a mysql server running outside the Docker container? I'm still very new to Docker so I wouldn't be surprised if that's the mistake. Any tips are appreciated 'cause I'm at a dead end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your docker-compose file looks wrong to me, try below docker-compose file.
I removed the links, network is much easier.

```
version: '3'
services:
    nginx:
        build: nginx
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - backend
        volumes:
            - ../:/app

    php:
        build: php-fpm
        volumes:
            - ../:/app
        working_dir: /app
        networks:
            - backend
        extra_hosts:
            - "site.dev: 172.17.0.1"


    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        restart: always
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'database_name'
            MYSQL_USER: 'username'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'password'
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password_root'
        networks:
            - backend
        ports:
            - '3306:3306'
        volumes:
            - ./my-db:/var/lib/mysql

networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

then use `database_host: db` in php file.
I would diagnose

- Check docker logs in the mysql container => no errors
- Login to the mysql container and login to mysql => no errors
- Login to mysql from the host (`mysql -u username -p` since you are mapping to 3306 port of the host)
- Make sure mysql.cnf doesn't block connect from outside(check
  bind-address in the mysql configuration if it 127.0.0.1 the its only
  allow to connect form locally, i would for now make it 0.0.0.0 or
  commented that line if exists)

  - `mysqld --verbose --help` => you will see all options
  - `mysqld --verbose --help | grep bind-address`=> check the bind-address
- Make sure the user i tried to login has enough privileges to
  connect(`SELECT user,host FROM mysql.user;`) check your user can
  connect from docker network => `172.*` or anywhere=> `%`

Comment: Still doesn't seem to work. It creates the mysql container properly, but I still can't connect to it with a DB manager and I still get the same error as before. `docker inspect` tells me the IP address is 172.19.0.4 and I added `expose: - "3306"` to docker-compose.yml, but like I said, still can't connect in any way.

Comment: were u able to u login to the container and connect with provided credentials to the mysql?

Comment: Yes, if I exec into the container I can log in using the mysql command, the issue lies in connecting to it from outside the container.

Comment: @Alex check the answer, i updated with the steps i would diagnose the issue.

Comment: I managed to solve it, with some more debugging I got more specific error messages, first Connection refused, then one about the server requesting an unknown authentication method after which I knew I was finally connected to the database. I managed to solve that error with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881212/2466375) answer, so I'm now in the process of importing a 1.6gb database dump.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is with your `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    database_host: 127.0.0.1
```

When you run compose, MySQL and PHP will run in their own containers which will have their own IPs: `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` from the `php` won't be able to connect to the `db` container. It's like you deployed PHP on a virtual machine `A` and MySQL to another virtual machine `B`, but you try to access MySQL from machine `A` by using `localhost` where you should specify machine `B` IP or hostname.

With Docker Compose the internal DNS will resolve the service name to it's container, so you can use something like:

```
parameters:
    # name of the service in compose should be resolved
    database_host: db
```

The error `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory` may be caused when the client tries to read MySQL socket usually present at `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` which is probably not present in your PHP container.