# PHP-mysqli can't connect to MySQL 8.0.16 running in a Docker

Tags: php, mysql, docker, mysqli, mysql-8.0

**Summary:**

- `mysql-server 8.0.16` is running *inside a Docker container*.
- php 7 + Apache2 + myslnd 5.0.12 + mysqld 5.6.22 are running *outside* Docker.

In PHP, mysqli fails thus:

```
mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1', 'test', 'test', 'test', 8016)

ERR: 2054 : The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
```

Meanwhile `mysql` can connect thus from *outside* Docker:

```
mysql  -P 8016 -h 127.0.0.1 -u test -ptest test
```

**Question:**  How can I get `mysqli_connect` working?

**Details:**

Here are some of the relevant GRANT entries.

```
mysql> select host, user, db, select_priv, grant_priv
                  from mysql.db where user='test';
+------------+------+------+-------------+------------+
| host       | user | db   | select_priv | grant_priv |
+------------+------+------+-------------+------------+
| 172.17.0.1 | test | test | Y           | N          |

mysql> select host, user, plugin, select_priv, grant_priv
                    from mysql.user where user='test';
+------------+------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+
| host       | user | plugin                | select_priv | grant_priv |
+------------+------+-----------------------+-------------+------------+
| 172.17.0.1 | test | mysql_native_password | N           | N          |
```

I found the /etc/my.cnf *inside* the docker image and enabled

```
default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

That allowed even an old (5.6) `mysql` to connect thus:

```
mysql  -P 8016 -h 127.0.0.1 -u test -ptest test
```

And, yes, it came back with a heading including

```
Server version: 8.0.16 MySQL Community Server - GPL
```

It seems that the commandline `mysql` knows about `mysql_native_password`, but
`mysqlnd` does not.

More version info:

```
PHP Version 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6
Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
```

`phpinfo` says this about `mysqlnd`:

```
Version:         mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b5c5906d452ec590732a93b051f3827e02749b83 $
Loaded plugins:  mysqlnd,debug_trace,auth_plugin_mysql_native_password,auth_plugin_mysql_clear_password,auth_plugin_sha256_password
API Extensions:  mysqli,pdo_mysql
```

`#docker ps` (shows port mapping):

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS                               NAMES
99193bedb36c        mysql/mysql-server:8.0.16   "/entrypoint.sh my..."   8 weeks ago         Up 12 hours (healthy)   33060/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8016->3306/tcp   o8016
```

PHP-CLI also fails to connect.

(Yes, I ran `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` at the appropriate time.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP with MySQL 8.0+ error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to)

Comment: @LinPy - Thanks, but I don't think it is the same.  Note that I already have `mysql_native_password` in the Grant table and my.cnf.  Also, mysqlnd _seems_ to be able to handle sha2 (see phpinfo).

Comment: you need to rebuild the container with `default-authentication-plugin`

Comment: @LinPy - It is not a dup.  The `ALTER` (Answers 1 and 3 of dup) has been done.  The `[mysqld]` setting (Ans 2) has been done,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've tried setting `default-authentication-plugin` in `my.cnf` - perhaps try to do it as a `command` arg instead? I had similar problems trying to auth, but this works for me in my `docker-compose.yml` - I never tried setting it in `my.cnf`

```
mysql:
    container_name: myapp-db
    image: mysql:8.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
     (snip)
```

(`command` taken from the Docker docs page for MySQL).

Comment: You are saying that the setting in the GRANTs and my.cnf are not sufficient?  That sounds like a bug.

Comment: I'm just saying what worked for me. The official mysql docker image has a launch script rather than running mysql directly - I haven't dug into it to see if there's some mechanism where it doesn't read the my.cnf file, sorry. The first thing I tried worked, so I moved on to my next problem...

Comment: I don't see it on https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server ; what page are you looking at?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/mysql/ - pretty sure this was the page. The 'command' method is in there as a sample config item, but my hazy memory has the page content a little different (it was definitely on the docs.docker.com site, though)

Comment: It's irritating that installing the package from docker would not work as-is.  I created a compose script similar to yours and got it to work.  Thanks.