# getting an "script artisan error 1" after composer install

Tags: php, laravel

After running the command below in my laravel project

> composer.phar install

I got an error:

> Script php artisan optimize handling the post-install-cmd event
>   returned with error code 1
>
> In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method
>   unknown t     o the client (SQL: select * from `options` where
>   `option_key` = currency_po     sition limit 1)
>
> In Connector.php line 68:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method
>   unknown t     o the client
>
> In Connector.php line 68:
>                                                                                     PDO::__construct(): The server requested authentication method unknown
>   to t     he client [caching_sha2_password]

Does anyone encounter the same error? I already tried running the command 'composer update' but still nothing happened.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to