# Can't connect to MySQL with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm following [this tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners/episodes/13?autoplay=true), I'm currently around minute 04:00 and I want to make a connection with my MySQL database through PDO. But my webpage will always give "Could not connect." when I'm trying to make the connection.
When I used PHPStorms inside Database program, I had to change my serverTimezone to Europe/Amsterdam and then I was able to connect to my db.

I tried to add the port number in the 'new PDO()' code.
I tried to change the timezone in the code and on my MySQL server but it gives this error;

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Amsterdam';
ERROR 1298 (HY000): Unknown or incorrect time zone: 'Europe/Amsterdam'
```

```
<?php

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost:dbname=mytodo', 'root', '');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Could not connect.');
}

$statement = $pdo->prepare('select * from todos');

$statement->execute();

var_dump($statement->fetchAll());

require 'index.view.php';
```

Extra information:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
+--------------------+---------------------+
| @@global.time_zone | @@session.time_zone |
+--------------------+---------------------+
| SYSTEM             | SYSTEM              |
+--------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: `mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'Europe/Amsterdam';` is not PHP, nor PDO. Please clarify the question. Is it a SQL query or PDO connection?

Comment: Okay, so I used the code of 'your common sense', I restarted my mysql services and then got this error:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

You can fix that with:
ALTER USER 'YOUR_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'ENTER_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE';

Comment: `ALTER USER 'YOUR_USER_NAME'` is not in this question.. also what are you attempting to do with that statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are following is very outdated.

A code connecting to PDO has to follow certain rules explained in my article [How to connect to MySQL with PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). In brief

- it should configure error reporting mode
- it should set the connection charset, the right way
- it shouldn't catch it's own errors to report them
- it should follow correct DSN syntax, without any extra decorations
- it also coud set a couple useful settings

So the code should be like this

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'mytodo';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8mb4';

$options = [
    \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    \PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => \PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
```

Here you can see the proper connection code that does a lot of things. Among them, it tells you what the actual problem is when your code cannot connect to database.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client

Comment: Yes! Now you know the problem. And the solution for this particular problem is easily Google-able, just like I said: this is a [well known problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to). Just remember - the problem could be anything and the key is to get the actual error message. The rest is simple

Comment: Okay, so I used the code of 'your common sense', I restarted my mysql services and then got this error: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client. You can fix that with: ALTER USER 'YOUR_USER_NAME'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'ENTER_YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE';

Answer (score 0):

You have error in code near localhost

Use semicolon in place of colon

Write this instead:

```
$pdo=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mytodo','root','');
```