# Mysql wokbench db connection with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

Hai iam using phpmyadmin for a long time. now i want to change to mysql workbench. so i start with basics How can i connect my db.
i tried this..

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306","root","","surendar");

`Warning: mysqli_connect(): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password]
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2054): The server requested authentication method unknown to the client`
correct me if i am wrong.. Thanks

Comment: You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52364415/5587982).