# Database migration not working in Laravel 7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I get this type of exception in all my Laravel projects.

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = orchid and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +34 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I tried to solve it through `.env` setup.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=orchid
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

But it's not working.

After then I installed `composer require doctrine/dbal` package in my Laravel project but it's not working. I cannot understand how to solve it.

Comment: I think this problem comes from mysql server. But where exactly problem cannot find out the proper solution on it. So please help for this problem.

Comment: remove the password and leave it as blank

Comment: Thanks for your advise. But MySQL server have default password is `password`. without password it is not worked.

Comment: Okay got you. Then do try php artisan config:cache command to clear the cache and then try. Hopefully it'll work

Comment: I also trying this. but it's not working. May be this problem comes from mysql server. other wise comes from MACOS new version. this problem comes from new project also.

Comment: Okay, Actually it seems that laravel is not able to authenticate your mysql server

Comment: please see:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53881212/10573560

Comment: I try this solution. It helps me.
1. Log in as root to mysql
2. Run this sql command:
`
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password
BY 'password';  `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try this solution. It helps me.

1. Log in as root to mysql
2. Run this sql command:
   `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`