# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory migrate problem in mac

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, macos, homebrew

i got problem in here so i setup mac for development then i install with brew mysql 5.7

but i can't migrate at all

then i got this error message

`Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')`

my .env looks like this

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

but i can login into mysql CLI with brew i still don't understand where is the problem

UPDATE :

this is solved by installing the `mysql_secure_installation`

source FIX PROBLEM : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xX9W5dmEpO0&t=284s

fixing user grant : [PHP with MySQL 8.0+ error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to)