# Trying to link Symfony to mySQL

Tags: mysql, symfony

Since this morning, I'm trying to connect Symfony to mySQL.

this is  my .env :

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:@127.0.0.1:3306/shop?serverVersion=5.7
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PWD=root
DATABASE_NAME=shop
DATABASE_HOST=127.0.0.1
```

this is my doctrine.yaml :

dbal:

```
# configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: '5.7'
    charset: utf8mb4
    host: 127.0.0.1
    port: 3306
    user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
    password: '%env(DATABASE_PWD)%'
    dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
```

When I'm doing the command :  bin/console doctrine:database:create

I have the error :
In CreateDatabaseDoctrineCommand.php line 82:

Connection does not contain a 'path' or 'dbname' parameter and cannot be created.

Can anyone have any idea of what is wrong ?

thanks

Comment: Try using `doctrine:
    dbal:
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'`

Comment: I have a new error : In PDOConnection.php line 31:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown t  
  o the client                                                                 
                                                                               
In PDOConnection.php line 27:
                                                                               
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown t  
  o the client

Comment: In your .env `DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/shop` ?

Comment: Are you sure can you connect to your 127.0.0.1 with 'root' user and 'root' password?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to

Comment: You're welcome @Amaury Neury

Comment: If there is any new error, please add it to your question by editing

Answer (score 0):

Try using in your .env:

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:root@127.0.0.1:3306/shop
```

In your doctrine.yaml:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        # configure these for your database server
        url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
```

See https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#configuring-the-database