# phpmyadmin login error 1045, need help fixing

Tags: phpmyadmin

i am currently setting up an old computer as a server and i am at the webserver part, but i currently have a problem where phpmyadmin wont let me login (at least from my main computer on the same network), it throws out error #1045. I currently have no way of testing a login directly from the computer but i need to be able to login from other comptuers on my network.

Anyone know a possible fix ?

Note: ive already tried to reset the mysql account passwords

[all the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mss26.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP with MySQL 8.0+ error: The server requested authentication method unknown to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52364415/php-with-mysql-8-0-error-the-server-requested-authentication-method-unknown-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL versions are you using? This is most likely a version incompatibility with MySQL and PHP; when using MySQL 8.0 or newer you'll need PHP 7.4 or newer, this error message suggests that your PHP installation is older than that. The best solution is to upgrade your PHP to 7.4 or newer. Which operating system does the server use and how have you installed PHP (using the package manager, manually compiling, using some prebuilt kit, etc)?

You could also see https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#i-get-an-error-message-about-unknown-authentication-method-caching-sha2-password-when-trying-to-log-in for more details.