# Where does the my.cnf resides on macOS High Sierra?

Tags: mysql, macos

I wanted to disable some options in the MySql server strict mode, but for some reason I'm not even able to find its configuration file (my.cnf)

Currently installed MySql:
Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.20, for macos10.12 (x86_64)

Output generated by

```sh
mysql --help
```

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:

- /etc/my.cnf
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- /usr/local/mysql/etc/my.cnf
- ~/.my.cnf

But there is no such file as my.conf

I had done some research work on SO but none of the advises has worked for me.

What I'm supposed to do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are defaults built into MySQL.  The configuration file(s), *if any*, override the defaults.

Note that the config files are not looked at except during startup.  So, editing or creating such a file has no effect until you restart `mysqld`.

If you mess up the syntax, `mysqld` will not start.  Then you need to find the error, either during startup, or in a log file.  (Or you could ask here "what is my syntax error".)

**As for the location, and name, of the config files that will be used:**

```
$ mysql --help
```

gives you the list for `mysql`, but perhaps you need it for the server, so try

```
$ mysqld --help --verbose
```

gives you long output; maybe 50 lines from the top, you should see something like:

```
Usage: mysqld [OPTIONS]

Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

You asked about `my.conf`; was that a typo?

Regardless, If those files are missing, you can create them, make them readable by mysql, and put things into it preceded by `[mysqld]` so that the server will see them.

**Personal override**

Regardless of what is in the defaults and/or config files, you can add to the last file given.  In the examples above that is 'hidden' `.my.cnf` in *your* home directory.  All you need to do is create a few lines:

```
[mysql]
some_setting = somevalue
[client]
some_setting = somevalue
```

That helps for the "mysql" commandline tool and/or other clients (maybe).

But if you need to make changes to the server `mysqld`, it needs to be in one of the other files.  Again, the minimum is something like

```
[mysqld]
some_setting = somevalue
```

Note the `mysqld` to refer to the *server*.  And remember to restart the service.

Another note:  If you see (in an existing config file), `!includedir ...`, then go to that directory to find any number of further files.  You could add your own file, say `z.cnf` (so it would be picked last) with the two (or more) lines as indicated above.

Comment: that's the point. @'L'l has recommended this approach also. But the question remains, how does it work without thoses config files? Where is this file on the OS system?  and yes I had already tried to create the file manually, coping some default my.cnf content found on the internet. After some time of crafting around I gave it completly up as the mysql server couldn't start anymore. For me seems the efford inadequate to my current issues

Comment: @ChristianFelix - I added 4 paragraphs to the beginning of my answer; I hope they address your concerns.

Comment: @ChristianFelix - and more at the end of my Answer.

Comment: that's the best answer so far. the bounty is yours.

Answer (score 4):

If you have installed `Mysql 8` or Above using the package installer from mysql website, then follow what i did

1. Create the config file in your home directory `vim ~/.my.cnf`
2. Do open `System preferences` in mac

[image]

3. Then Select the configuration file you created on the option.
   [image]

Comment: My Answer helped in in 2022 when i configured on new MAC.

Answer (score 3):

The content in [this](https://hansprueller.lbs-logics.com/?p=419) website says.

I had the urgent need to configure some specific stuff in MySQL 5.7 on my developer machine, a MacBook Pro running Mac OS Sierra. Unfortunately, I did not find a my.cnf file that could be customized anywhere?

Internet research showed that MySQL Database Server on Mac OS runs without a my.cnf config file by default, simply started with default values.

Luckily, it is pretty simple to customize the MySQL Server installation by creating and editing a custom my.cnf file like this:

`sudo cp /usr/local/mysql/support-files/my-default.cnf  /etc/my.cnf
Then edit / customize the /etc/my.cnf` file as required and restart your MySQL Server.

Or you can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757261/11333553)

Comment: Link-only answers aren't generally helpful. Every answer should at least give a significant amount of value even if the user isn't able to follow the links (e.g. because the content has been removed). Links can be useful *additions*, but I'd recommend against posting an answer which is *nothing* but links.

Comment: I had done some resarch work before posting this issue also... but as stated previously, there is no such file as my-default .cnf on my system.

Comment: Unfortunately, different systems (Windows, Ubuntu, Linux, Max, WAMP, LAMP, Percona, etc) choose to put the config files and/or default samples in different places with different names.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$ locate mysql | grep my.cnf
```

It should reveal the location(s) if it exists.

Comment: no results. I had also used: sudo find / -name *.cnf -type f ... and found some files but nothing of the related to mysql

Comment: @ChristianFelix: what is the output of `which mysql`?

Comment: also no results...mysql server is still running

Comment: @ChristianFelix: That makes absolutely no sense; try `ps -ax | grep mysql`

Comment: _mysql              96   0,0  0,1  4677960   4348   ??  Ss   27Apr19   0:29.64 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring --early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so
philip

Comment: @ChristianFelix: Okay, I think I know what's going on now... the file actually doesn't exist on your system and you'll need to create it. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757261/499581

Comment: @ChristianFelix: Did you create the file manually as it was explained? If `my.cnf` is not in `/etc` then you’ll need to ensure it is.

Comment: I wanted rather to copy it from some source file to the destination file.... this  source file has to exists somewhere..

Comment: @ChristianFelix: If you want a default example try looking inside `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/` then make a copy of it and modify it however you want.