# Can someone help me with functions in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, function, mysql-workbench

I run the following script:

```
USE MODERN_FAMILY;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS compare_news; 
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION compare_news(n INT, m INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)

BEGIN
DECLARE s VARCHAR(20);

IF n>m THEN SET s='>'; 
ELSEIF n=m THEN SET s='='; 
ELSE SET s='<';
END IF;
SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ',m);
RETURN s; END;$$
```

First script returns this error :

```
Error Code: 1418. This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled (you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable).
```

Then, I run this:

```
USE MODERN_FAMILY;
SELECT compare_news(2,5);
```

It returns this error:

```
Error Code: 2014. Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now.
```

Does someone know if I have an error with the script? Or is related to my SQL configuration?

Comment: Works fine for me so 'is related with my SQL configuration'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable controls whether binary logging should trust the stored function creators for not to create unsafe stored functions.

Reference: [Stored Program Logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-logging.html)

> When you create a stored function, you must declare either that it is
>   deterministic or that it does not modify data. Otherwise, it may be
>   unsafe for data recovery or replication.
>
> By default, for a CREATE FUNCTION statement to be accepted, at least
>   one of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, or READS SQL DATA must be specified
>   explicitly. Otherwise an error occurs:
>
> `ERROR 1418 (HY000): This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL,
>   or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled
>   (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators
>   variable)`
>
> To relax the preceding conditions on function creation (that you must
>   have the SUPER privilege and that a function must be declared
>   deterministic or to not modify data), set the global
>   log_bin_trust_function_creators system variable to 1.

**Solution 1:** Make your function which doesn't manipulate data or deterministic in nature

```
CREATE FUNCTION `compare_news`(
    `n` INT,
    `m` INT
) RETURNS VARCHAR(20) CHARSET latin1 LANGUAGE SQL DETERMINISTIC NO SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER COMMENT '' 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE s VARCHAR(20); 
    IF n>m THEN 
        SET s='>'; 
    ELSEIF n=m THEN 
        SET s='='; 
    ELSE 
        SET s='<'; 
    END IF; 

    SET s = CONCAT(n, ' ', s, ' ',m); 
    RETURN s; 
END
```

**Solution 2**: Enable MySQL to trust such functions by setting mysql `log_bin_trust_function_creators` variable to `ON`.

Reference: [log_bin_trust_function_creators](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_bin_trust_function_creators)

```
SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;
```

The variable will change upon restart if you do not update the config to reflect the change.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for all the explanation. I read that it is necessary to change as well the configuration file .ini but I have a Mac how can I do that? Do you know or is not necessary? I really appreciate your time.

Comment: @HeinerRomeroLeiva, if you use `solution 1` then you don't have to set that variable.

Comment: This might be helpful for future reference. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos