# MySQL server dies or doesn't start on Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4

Tags: mysql, macos-catalina

I installed the latest version of MySQL mysql-8.0.20-macos10.15-x86_64

When I start the server, it doesn't start. When I look into logs I see the following message:

```
sudo tail -n10  /usr/local/mysql/data/MacBook-Pro.local.err

2020-04-29T19:14:15.781011Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/tmp/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
2020-04-29T19:14:15.875568Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2020-04-29T19:14:15.881149Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-000067] [Server] unknown variable 'query_cache_size=32M'.
2020-04-29T19:14:15.882207Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2020-04-29T19:14:16.820509Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.20)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

I cannot find where `query_cache_size` is coming from and I didn't set it.

This is the list of files/folder in MySQL folder:

```
LICENSE       bin           docs          keyring       man           support-files
README        data          include       lib           share
```

Comment: Somewhere in your system is a `my.cnf` file. Where that might be located depends on how you installed it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos

Comment: Thanks, found the file using this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58981341/902952. Still running into issues during startup. Debugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix.
Documenting my troubleshooting/fix steps, so that it can save someone else hours of debugging.

- Located the my.cnf file `/private/etc/my.cnf`, and noticed that a lot of configs were still conflicting as I was disabling them one by one. So, I simply renamed my.cnf to my.cnf.bak i.e. forcing MySQL to create a brand new file (now god knows where it created new one, that is a mystery for some other day :) )
- Started the server using `sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start`
- The server was still not starting and it was erroring with `Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35`
- So, I killed the ghost mysql process `ps aux | grep mysql` and `kill <process-name>`
- Yay! server started running.