# mysql - ERROR 1819 (HY000) Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Tags: mysql

there are many posts out there about resolving this issue, however, none of them work for me. I am signed in as root on MySQL within my computer. after signing in with `$ mysql -u root -p` and enter my password I enter in and try to create a user with `CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost';` but then I get the error:

> ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

after printing my variables with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';` I get:

```
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| Variable_name                        | Value  |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
| validate_password.check_user_name    | ON     |
| validate_password.dictionary_file    |        |
| validate_password.length             | 8      |
| validate_password.mixed_case_count   | 1      |
| validate_password.number_count       | 1      |
| validate_password.policy             | MEDIUM |
| validate_password.special_char_count | 1      |
+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

I have tried with [this](https://defragged.org/2020/02/29/mysql-error-1819-hy000-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements/) solution as well as [this](https://hoststud.com/resources/resolved-mysql-error-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements.464/), however, when trying uninstall the validate password with: `UNINSTALL plugin validate_password;` I get:

> ERROR 1305 (42000): PLUGIN validate_password does not exist

whenever I try to set a variable I get the error:

> ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'validate_password_policy'

in between the quotation marks above can be replaced with any variable.
I am correctly signed in as root. and just starting to lose my mind over this.

thank you for your help.

#### Edits:

I have tried to find my `my.cnf` file following[this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37729535/8635165) and while I have found it any editing to the file causes a socket error:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

I have also tried uninstalling and reinstally MySQL through homebrew however the error continues with the policy requirements.

Comment: Have you tried adding the variable setting directly in my.cnf/my.ini?

Comment: my computer (macOS) says that I have a `my.cnf` but I can't locate them in the directories stated. for example following the command `$ mysql --verbose --help | grep my.cnf` I get `/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf` but when navigating to the destinations I can't find them to open the file. for example: `cat /etc/my.cnf` gives me:  `cat: my.cnf: No such file or directory`

Comment: Try this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos  .. see if it could help

Comment: I've tried that and making the correct modifications but when I do there is a connection issue with sockets and won't allow for any connection. I've also tried removing MySQL and reinstalling it through homebrew and still get the same error as above. I have no idea what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the error was that I cannot create a user without a password: `mysql> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost';` this will fail because I cannot create a user without stating the password, even if I will assign it later I need to create *and* set the password.

So:

`mysql> CREATE USER 'test'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password1';`

`Password1` should be replaced with your desired password.

Answer (score 0):

after trying with some simple passwords, I got this error, then checked the `variables` table with this `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`
[image]

the output shows that the policy is already set to `low`, then what I did is just followed what is mentioned here to build the password, which is like, using at least 8 chars, 1 number at least, mixing of case letters etc. After that performed the command `'ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password by 'mysql0_rT';` and then there was no error.