# PHPMyAdmin: ERROR 1819 (HY000) - Password does not satisfy the current policy requirements

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, ubuntu-20.04

Firstly, please do not link me to any of these posts as I have already read them in their entirety and nothing helped:

- [mysql cannot grant privilege to user, getting error: ERROR 1819 (HY000): Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37762895/mysql-cannot-grant-privilege-to-user-getting-error-error-1819-hy000-your-pa)
- [Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094726/your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-requirements)
- [mysql - ERROR 1819 (HY000) Your password does not satisfy the current policy requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62060868/mysql-error-1819-hy000-your-password-does-not-satisfy-the-current-policy-req)

I keep getting the above error (in the title) when setting up or reconfiguring PHPMyAdmin on Ubuntu Server 20.04.

To be clear, this is the the terminal view when entering the password that prompts the error

[image]

And now the error itself

[image]

---

Here is the result when I run the following command:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'validate_password%';`

[image]

I enter the following password (obviously fake but still meets the password requirements above): `JoeBloggs2018$`

For my own sanity, a breakdown of the password:

- Length: 14 Chars
- Uppercase Count: 2 (Mixed Case = true)
- Number Count: 4
- Special Char Count: 1

This then results in the error which I do not understand. I didn't want to lower the password requirements however I did just for troubleshooting purposes and it still didn't work.

If anyone could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I had the same problem with my students. We fixed this by creating the phpmyadmin user before installing phpmyadmin:

```
CREATE USER 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH 'caching_sha2_password' BY 'Phpmy@dm1n';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON phpmyadmin.* TO 'phpmyadmin'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Then:

```
sudo apt install phpmyadmin
```

When prompted for the password, enter the password provided when creating the user (Phpmy@dm1n).

Answer (score 5):

I found another solution [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-20-04-de).

1. Select 'abort'
2. `sudo mysql -p`
3. `mysql> UNINSTALL COMPONENT "file://component_validate_password";`
4. `mysql> exit`
5. `sudo apt install phpmyadmin`
6. `mysql> INSTALL COMPONENT "file://component_validate_password";`

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t have a bunch of user accounts connecting to your database server, then you *may* be able to get away with one of the two following options:

#### Option 1 — Change the Password Policy

Your password policy is currently set to `MEDIUM`. You can easily change this to `LOW` in order to handle easily-cracked passwords. In MySQL, as root (or an equivalent), execute this statement:

```
SET GLOBAL validate_password.policy=LOW;
```

#### Option 2 — Remove the Password Validation Module

This is very much a Rod-from-God approach, but it gets the job done ***for local environments***:

1. Connect to the server as root
2. Remove the plug-in:

   ```
   UNINSTALL PLUGIN validate_password;
   ```

   In the event of an error, use:

   ```
   UNINSTALL COMPONENT 'file://component_validate_password';
   ```
3. Get on with your work

> These solutions are **not** recommended for a production or Internet-accessible instance. Please don’t expose yourself to unnecessary risk.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I actually already tried option 1 as mentioned however that didn't work. Option 2 I was uncomfortable with doing for the reasons you stated. I'll keep looking but it looks like it's isolated somewhat to the PHPMyAdmin setup process and if you disable the `validate_password` plugin only temporarily and then install it again, you password is both accepted and secure - I'll add an answer once I get conclusive information.

Comment: @matigo - Good to know, but this doesn't answer the question. His password appears strong enough, but mysql/phpmyadmin setup script rejects it. Why?