# mysql command returns ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abdullah'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, bash, path

Something tells me this is a stupid question but I'm a newbie when it comes to the Terminal. I've been searching everywhere for weeks with no luck so far..

Not sure if the following are relevant but am providing them just in case

```
MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2016, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports)
macOS Catalina version 10.15.6 (19G2021)
```

**Problem:**

Every time I type `mysql` in the Terminal, it returns

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'abdullah'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

What is strange is that `abdullah` is my MacBook Pro account name and I don't understand how it got there!
Anyways, when I type `mysql -u root -p` it asks for a password then logs me in and works just fine. Only when I type `mysql` by itself, returns the error message.

I might have missed up the `$PATH` which caused this problem. I remember adding the following at some point in the past:
`echo 'export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p:$PATH' >>~/.bash_profile` but then I reset the content of `~/.bash_profile` file to be as follows:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"

export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin"
```

Here's the output when I login to `mysql` as a `root` and `SELECT Host, User FROM mysql.user;`

```
+-----------+---------------+
| Host      | User          |
+-----------+---------------+
| %         | almokain001   |
| localhost | mysql.session |
| localhost | mysql.sys     |
| localhost | root          |
+-----------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe the issue is that if you don't use the `-u` flag with the MySQL client, it will use the OS user.   That's why it works for `mysql -u root -p`.  Try replacing root with the user you want to log in as.

Comment: You can change the default user used when you type `mysql` via `~/.my.cnf`.

Comment: @MBeale: There is no intention to log in as a different user than `root`. I expect MySQL to log me in, just like it used to do when first installed, by typing `mysql` in the terminal.

Comment: @jordanm: Couldn't find `~/.my.cnf`. According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10757261/5923981), "the OS X installation does not use a my.cnf, and MySQL just uses the default values."