# Resolving confusion over mysql location to recognize and run database

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, macos

Given a series of legacy issues, mysql was installed on an OS X machine (10.13) via a community server installation - not homebrew.

By accident homebrew was invoked to launch mysql.  Now the database is not accessible, although the folder does exist in path

```
/usr/local/mysql/data/thedb_development
```

mysql is an alias for `mysql-5.6.40-macos10.13-x86_64`
homebrew mysql references were subsequently removed and `brew cleanup` run.
Rails's `database.yml` defines:

```
host: 127.0.0.1
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

How can the system and rails be hooked to the `thedb_development` and run?

Comment: You need a my.cnf file for that please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos