# Where to add my.cnf configuration file for mysql in mac Catalina OS

Tags: mysql

I need to load data into mysql and for that i need to add this file or edit this file. I am not able to find this file and create into the right location.

I tried adding file in my root.

```
[mysqld]
secure_file_priv               = ''
```

Its still coming as null.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";
+------------------+-------+
| Variable_name    | Value |
+------------------+-------+
| secure_file_priv | NULL  |
```

I tried adding the file here also but it did not work.

/usr/local/mysql/support-files

Mysql is not picking this configuration up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Location of my.cnf file on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757169/location-of-my-cnf-file-on-macos)

Answer (score 0):

You can create file like `/etc/my.cnf` and

if you want to see example file on mac  you can get at `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/`.