# MySQL 8 fails to start after adding configuration with default-time-zone

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL 8 on MacOS using native [packages](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/macos-installation-pkg.html).

`default-time-zone` is set by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75540862/6134928) instructions:

```
sudo cat /etc/my.cnf
[mysqld]
default-time-zone = +00:00
```

After the server restart I can see that the `default-time-zone` is set to `SYSTEM` instead to `+00:00`:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone;
SYSTEM
```

I then added the configuration path via MacOS System Setting -> MySQL -> Configuration -> Configuration File:
[image]

However the server fails to start. Here is a content of `/usr/local/mysql-8.0.33-macos13-arm64/data/mysqld.local.err`:

```
2023-09-07T23:08:43.295201Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.33) starting as process 20500
2023-09-07T23:08:43.297324Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2023-09-07T23:08:43.303655Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2023-09-07T23:08:43.382999Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2023-09-07T23:08:43.464408Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2023-09-07T23:08:43.464425Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2023-09-07T23:08:43.474693Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /tmp/mysqlx.sock
2023-09-07T23:08:43.474715Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.33'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2023-09-07T23:10:02.803353Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.33).
2023-09-07T23:10:04.804999Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 8  user: 'root'.
2023-09-07T23:10:04.805260Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 9  user: 'root'.
2023-09-07T23:10:04.805402Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 10  user: 'root'.
2023-09-07T23:10:04.805660Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 12  user: 'root'.
2023-09-07T23:10:04.805976Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010909] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 13  user: 'root'.
2023-09-07T23:10:05.738712Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.33)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: please run `select timediff(now(),convert_tz(now(),@@session.time_zone,'+00:00'));` and see what system actually is

Comment: @nbk The result is `-5:00:00`. I updated the original post. I think the problem is that the server is unable to load the configuration file and fails to start.

Comment: see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63674/how-to-identify-the-user-who-issued-mysql-shutdown-command