# MAMP admin error, mysql not accessible

Tags: mysql, mamp

I get 'Error: Could not connect to MySQL server!' when I try to access the MAMP admin through a browser.

According the the MAMP application, mysql and Apache both start but sites that use databases and the MAMP admin are inaccessible.

I tried running:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin -u root -p password NEWPASSWORD
```

and the feedback is:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)'
```

Can anyone help me? How do I change the mysql password in MAMP?

Comment: Have you changed the password or do you need the default? (default is apparently "" or `root` http://aralbalkan.com/760)

Comment: I tried both and it's neither.

Comment: Not sure but you can read up on [access denied errors](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html). Also note  [MAMP doesn't have a my.cnf file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/678645/does-mysql-included-with-mamp-not-include-a-config-file) by default.

Answer (score 0):

Your command should be like this -

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I get `mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock' exists!`

Comment: I have tried suggested command. It works, the password was changed. About new error, have a look at this documentation page - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/can-not-connect-to-server.html