# MySQL my.cnf auto resetting

Tags: php, mysql, mamp

When I modify the file `mamp/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` and then restart MySQL all changes are reverted back to the original state.

Does anyone know how to fix this? It seems that `my.cnf` is created every time MySQL starts.

Comment: This may help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/2869707/1011527

Answer (score 0):

File `mamp/tmp/mysql/my.cnf` is, as the path says, temporary. It's automatically generated on MySQL start based on other configs.

You should use `MAMP/conf/my.cnf` instead. If the file does not exist then create a new one.