# MySQL Server won't start when I select 'Start Servers' on MAMP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, mamp

I'm a complete noob so please explain as simply as possible to me! Note: I am using a Mac (OS X YOSEMITE) and running MAMP.

I have been to both the Apache server and MySQL but a couple of hours ago the computer crashed and, once I restarted the computer, the MySQL Server would not load.

I tried going directly to localhost:8888/phpMyAdmin but produces an error:

"#2002 - No such file or directory — The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured)."

"mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory"

Here is the latest error code (I think):

```
161119 16:53:04 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
2016-11-19 16:53:04 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2016-11-19 16:53:04 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.33) starting as process 24189 ...
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1606268 and 1606268 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1640621 in the ib_logfiles!
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2016-11-19 16:53:04 24189 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace logintest/user uses space ID: 3 at filepath: ./logintest/user.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_relay_log_info.ibd
2016-11-19 16:53:04 7fff7b3a7300  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./mysql/slave_relay_log_info.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
161119 16:53:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

What do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33829888/innodb-attempted-to-open-a-previously-opened-tablespace)

Comment: @JakeN not a bad dupe to look at

Comment: Sorry I don't understand? What do I have to do?

Comment: Jake showed a dupe. Click on that link. See if any of those steps help and report back.

Comment: I didn't understand the steps that were given :/ plus, I'm using MAMP whereas the duplicate was using XAMP!

Comment: Possibly not a dup of that one -- because it _might_ be OS related, and the filesystem handling between WAMP (Windows) and MAMP (MAC) are radically different.

Comment: I realized that. There was a mention of a different stack on the Mac from user Tarun (in an answer), barely related, so I left this question alone and pinged Rick elsewhere. Thx guys.

Answer (score 0):

"Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace." -- That smells like one of these:

- There are two copies of MySQL and both are trying to run.  Search carefully for a Service running mysqld.
- Somehow you have a *hard* link between files, probably .ibd files.