# size request mysql

Tags: sql, request, size

i don't found in mamp where i can change the query size , i am using spring boot

Packet for query is too large (9 611 783 > 4 194 304). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2869707/1415262

Comment: @FelipeZavan thank you , but i try the solution and there is no new effect, i try many solution in internet and i still get the probleme, please i am using MAMP .In the solution they purpose to creat a file and add some configurartion like [mysqld] and the variable name and size it doen't work , i also try by command line, the same , i used to put the folder my.cnf in library and nothing new , please do you have solution ?